# Cocoapod path reference error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I have newly added cocoapods into my application, now getting “parser error” while compiling the code in client machine, But the same source code working fine in my system (without any changes).
Please find below error along with screen shot.

**../../../FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAccessToken.h**

[image]

And also i have added this tag ($(inherited) - > non-recursive) into below paths in Target -> Build settings.

**Header Search Path,
Framework Search path,
Library Search Path.**

i hope this is cocoapods path reference issue, Please any one help me out of this issue.

**Note:** Have sent file to client as a .zip.

Comment: don't looks like pods issue

Comment: @Misha actually, i need to know why this issue occurring in only client end. Can u tell me why this issue happening.

Comment: the error is says you are missing parenthesis , I could help more if you could post more detail screenshot

Comment: @Misha thanks for your response, Have solved this issue by, sent source file to another machine(Client Place) as a .tar.gz file format instead of .zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i came up with answer, I have sent source file to client end(other systems) **as a .tar.gz format instead of .zip file.**

This is solved my issue.Hope it will help for some one in the future.....

[image]